# Как поместить текст из программы в виженты QTextEdit?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты, qtextedit

Смысл задачи следующий:

1. При входе в приложение, 
   в первых двух окошках `[QTextEdit] (Сколько будет [ ... ]` и `[ ... ])` 
   уже будут сформированы числа, так:

   `a = random.randint(1, 299)`
   `b = 300 - a`
2. Пользователь вводит результат в окно `(Ответ: [ ... ])`
3. Нажимает на кнопку `[Окей?]`.

---

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно поместить
два случайных  числа в 1-е и 2-е окошко `QTextEdit`, которые объединены под  общим названием (**`Сколько будет...`**)?

---

****Console Code:****

```
import random
a = random.randint (1,299)
b = 300 - a

print ("Сколько будет", a, "+", b, "?")
res = int(input("Введите  число: "))

while res != 300:
    print ("\nНе верно, попробуй ещё раз... ")
    res = int(input("Введите  число: "))

res = 300
print ("\n\n****АЗАЗЗАЗАЗА ... Ну Вы поняли****\n")
```

---

**design.py:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(226, 221)
        MainWindow.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 91, 21))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 150, 91, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(self.centralwidget)
        self.splitter.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 91, 61))
        self.splitter.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.splitter.setObjectName("splitter")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.splitter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.splitter)
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.splitter_2 = QtWidgets.QSplitter(self.centralwidget)
        self.splitter_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 161, 31))
        self.splitter_2.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.splitter_2.setObjectName("splitter_2")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.splitter_2)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.splitter_2)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.splitter_2)
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.splitter_2)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Суперпрограмма"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сколько будет"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Окей?"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ:"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "+"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "?"))
```

---

**main.py:**

```
import sys
# Импортируем наш интерфейс из файла
from design import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку        
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction)

    # Пока пустая функция которая выполняется
    # при нажатии на кнопку                  
    def MyFunction(self):
       pass #заглушка
    
if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Визуально задача выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
import random                                             # +++

from PyQt5  import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from design import *

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.myRandom()                                   # +++

        # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку        
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction)

# +++                 
    def MyFunction(self):
        # pass #заглушка
        rez = self.ui.plainTextEdit.toPlainText()
        if rez:
            if (self.a + self.b) == int(rez):
                QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'yes', "Ответ правильный!.")
                self.myRandom()
            else:
                QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Ошибка', "Ваш ответ неправильный.")
        else:
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Внимание!', "Вы не ввели ответ. Введите ответ.")

# +++       
    def myRandom(self):
        self.a = random.randint (1,299)
        self.b = 300 - self.a

        self.ui.textEdit.setText(str(self.a))
        self.ui.textEdit_2.setText(str(self.b))
        self.ui.plainTextEdit.setPlainText('')


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

design.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(226, 221)
        MainWindow.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 91, 21))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 150, 91, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(self.centralwidget)
        self.splitter.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 91, 61))
        self.splitter.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.splitter.setObjectName("splitter")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.splitter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.splitter)
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")

        self.splitter_2 = QtWidgets.QSplitter(self.centralwidget)
        self.splitter_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 161, 31))
        self.splitter_2.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.splitter_2.setObjectName("splitter_2")

        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.splitter_2)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")

        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.splitter_2)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")

        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.splitter_2)
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")

        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.splitter_2)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Суперпрограмма"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сколько будет"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Окей?"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ:"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "+"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "?"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @217323 Вы меняли файл design.py?  Вылезает ошибка: 

"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Esquire\Desktop\Для реда\main.py", line 43, in <module>
    myapp = MyWin()
  File "C:\Users\Esquire\Desktop\Для реда\main.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.myRandom()
  File "C:\Users\Esquire\Desktop\Для реда\main.py", line 36, in myRandom
    self.ui.textEdit.setText(str(self.a))
AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'textEdit'"

Comment: @AlexandrS  мне кажется, что я ничего не менял, проверте.

Comment: @217323 В этом вопросе Я использовал ****UI**** - первоначальный (НЕ тот, что Вы переписали в предыдущим вопросе).    Вы использовали UI от сюда или из предыдущего вопроса?

Comment: @AlexandrS я взял `.ui` с ввашего вопроса. Все работает.